# "Quick Access" for all workspace files?

Tags: eclipse

It seems that this handy "Quick Access" window does not show the items available via the project explorer. Instead it only allows navigation to items that already have opened editors.

I haven't found a way to configure this and am starting to suspect this is not yet implemented. But I would love to have a quick way to access workspace items without using the mouse, how do you do that?

Comment: In Eclipse Juno CDT, some files are listed and some files are not, irrespective of opened or not.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> +<kbd>R</kbd> to quickly search and open a file of any types in the workspace

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> +<kbd>T</kbd> to quickly search and open the source code of your java classes and the 3rd parties jar that your project uses.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you want is the "Open Resource" command. Control/command-shift-R.